# How to add new bone to my current control rig for animation?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, unity

I have a model which I rigged with the Mixamo addon (it's humanoid). Now I have to add a new bone (or something, probably it could be an object Empty) to make animation for ball (run with ball - new bone it was supposed to be for ball) and then a mesh will be added to the bone in Unity. I don't know how to do this. Once I added the bone to the armature and it worked with animation (but I think it wasn't control rigged bone) and in Unity animation doesn't work properly - this the bone animation.

Here's a video demonstration in [Blender](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lEpOb3LuzE8dYUgiobYBjG4IsOzBhDzt/view?usp=sharing) and in [Unity](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZXoPNw6oUMYVOhPvan-96LLDOwg3NjHe/view?usp=sharing)

[Download blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pE6rQ9D7hBVZTlxrYkJDOujDlja_Q-uo/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi, welcome! Just a heads up that you can attach images to your question in a way that they directly appear inline with your text. This might make your question more accessible. :)

Answer (score -1):

So the problem was in unity,If you use humanoid rig it doesn't show extra bones in animators so in unity you should active this bones manual -> here is the answer https://forum.unity.com/threads/humanoid-rigs-and-extra-bones.360979/
If you have exportes file (fbx) with armature and baked animations in it In inspectore you have to go to animation tab -> go to MASK ( bottom in this window) then open transform tab and find bones wihich you want to be active in my case it was bone named *ball_control and then click apply _> in your export file it will create new animation xx_1 and this animation will show your extra bones.

Maybe someone use this

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.